# In d3 how to calculate dynamically width and edge?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, graph, d3tree

**How to calculate the dy and width value dynamically? if the tree strcture changes every time.**

[code Used](https://observablehq.com/@d3/collapsible-tree)

below width will suit for the provided Json for a demo purpose.
dy = 154.66666666666666
width = 928

but if the json dynamically? and the same code doesnt work for below json
JSON:

```js
{
  "name": "flare",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "analytics",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "cluster",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "AgglomerativeCluster",
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": 1,
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "name": 2,
                      "children": [
                        {
                          "name": 3,
                          "children": [
                            {
                              "name": 4,
                              "children": [
                                {
                                  "name": 5,
                                  "children": [
                                    {
                                      "name": 6,
                                      "value": 6
                                    }
                                  ],
                                  "value": 5
                                }
                              ],
                              "value": 4
                            }
                          ],
                          "value": 3
                        }
                      ],
                      "value": 2
                    }
                  ],
                  "value": 1
                }
              ],
              "value": 3938
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**need a help to calculate width and dy dynamically..**

Comment: I have been looking for a solution for this too. It seems not possible to set the chart's width based on the amount of data. You have to set the width beforehand.

Comment: thanks looking for solution  not sure how we can fix this.

Comment: The only solution I found was to parse the data beforehand and guess how wide the chart will need to be for that data.

Comment: is it hit and trial or based on some depth we can give width?

Comment: That totally depends on the type of D3 chart and the shape of the data. In my case I drew a Tree chart so I had to count the amount of branches in the data. I guessed that every level needed about 300 pixels ... But there should be a better way! 

Comment: `dy = width / 6` in the linked example. 6 is the the max depth of the array in the example. Make that dynamic based on the max depth of the array.

Comment: @SmokeyShakers i have given try, instead of 6 tried to provide depth of the tree but mean time static width also should be changed.. but i am struck there.

Comment: @Kokodoko ya i am trying to d3 tree chart only minimum SVG width i have taken as window size. and tried to increase by some amount.. but this is not better approach.

Comment: Your `dy`  and `width` are not independent.  One is a function of the other.  You could write width as `width = dy * n`  where `n` is the max depth.